# Searching for tips on a good SWING-GUI plugin for Eclipse with low learningcurve

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, swing, plugins

My requirements are: Easy to understand, free/good price, low learningcurve.

So far I've heard of Matisse4MyEclipse, but that costs and I'm not familiar with "myEclipse" at all.

Others have tipped about Jigloo, which seems fairly nice.

Any tips to what you consider to be the be the most suitable plugin for Eclipse is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Or take a completely different route and use Groovy Swing Builder: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Swing+Builder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Free and good:

http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/

Comment: Thanks alot. Downloaded Windowbuilder Pro and it seems good so far!

Answer (score 3):

As of this moment, the latest version of WindowBuilder is available here...

http://code.google.com/javadevtools/download-wbpro-beta.html

WindowBuilder is quite a powerful tools, so your learning curve will vary depending on the type of app you are building and the types of layout managers and widgets that you use. The WB docs themselves are quite extensive, but intentionally focus on the tool itself and not the APIs that it supports (Swing, SWT and GWT).

http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wbpro/index.html

For info on those APIs, you should refer to the docs and tutorials provided by their respective vendors.